# How can I get current theme's action bar background color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-color, android-theme

I was trying to make my navigation drawer's background always match with the action bar's background color.

So that, every time, if the theme changes both background will change automatically.

I looked into [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html), but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ActionBar` API doesn't have a way to retrieve the current background `Drawable` or color.

However, you could use `Resources.getIdentifier` to call `View.findViewById`, retrieve the `ActionBarView`, then call `View.getBackground` to retrieve the `Drawable`. Even so, this still won't give you the color. The only way to do that would be to convert the `Drawable` into a `Bitmap`, then use some sort of [color analyzer](https://github.com/MichaelEvans/ColorArt) to find the dominant color.

Here's an example of retrieving the `ActionBar` `Drawable`.

```
    final int actionBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
    final View actionBar = findViewById(actionBarId);
    final Drawable actionBarBackground = actionBar.getBackground();
```

But it seems like the easiest solution would be to create your own attribute and apply it in your themes.

Here's an example of that:

**Custom attribute**

```
<attr name="drawerLayoutBackground" format="reference|color" />
```

**Initialize the attribute**

```
<style name="Your.Theme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="drawerLayoutBackground">@color/your_color_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Theme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="drawerLayoutBackground">@color/your_color_light</item>
</style>
```

Then in the layout that contains your `DrawerLayout`, apply the `android:background` attribute like this:

```
android:background="?attr/drawerLayoutBackground"
```

Or you can obtain it using a `TypedArray`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {
            R.attr.drawerLayoutBackground
    });
    try {
        final int drawerLayoutBackground = a.getColor(0, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

}
```

Comment: actionBar.getBackground() returns me null. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @kalehv do you have a background set using getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(...) ? If non is set you would indeed get a null value.